# Error in JS Bin - "YUI is not defined" -

Tags: javascript, yui, jsbin

I have a simple code in JS Bin:
https://jsbin.com/tutuku/edit?html,js,console,output

And I'm getting this error: "YUI is not defined".
From what I understand, probably YUI node is not loaded at the moment YUI is called.
Is there a simple solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YUI refuses to load over https.
To run jsbin example change its url and yui url to `http://`.
http://jsbin.com/wexaxofika/edit?html,js,console,output